# How fix input label of OutlinedInput

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, input-mask

I'm playing with material ui and build a project and I needed make a TextField with mask
with react-imask:

https://mui.com/en/material-ui/react-text-field/#integration-with-3rd-party-input-libraries

But I tried with OutlinedInput but the label crashes:

```html
<FormControl variant="standard">
        <InputLabel htmlFor="formatted-text-mask-input">react-imask</InputLabel>
        <OutlinedInput
          value={values.textmask}
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="textmask"
          id="formatted-text-mask-input"
          inputComponent={TextMaskCustom as any}
        />
      </FormControl>
```

Empty

[image: outlinedInput empty]

Filled

[image]

Codesandbox box

https://codesandbox.io/s/problem-with-3rd-party-input-libraries-cygxss?file=/demo.tsx

Codesandbox result link:
https://cygxss.csb.app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you don't just use a `TextField` with `variant` set to "outlined"?

The MUI example is just showing different methods of using their components and the `FormControl` composition is done in greater complexity within `TextField`.

**Solution**

```
<TextField
    label="react-imask"
    id="formatted-text-mask-input"
    name="textmask"
    value={values.textmask}
    onChange={handleChange}
    InputProps={{
        inputComponent: TextMaskCustom as any
    }}
/>
```

**Brief Look at Form Control**

It appears as though you have an `OutlinedInput` but are telling the `FormControl` it is "standard", fixing this puts the label in the right spot, but it does not properly break the border of the fieldset as intended.

If you need to manually control the composition of the individual parts (`FormControl`, `InputLabel`, `OutlinedInput`, etc) you can see how MUI compose `TextField` in [GitHub](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/TextField/TextField.js).

Comment: Thanks @jacob-smit . I changed to react-input-mask and works perfectly.
I thank to you for your time

Comment: I did make the changes you propose. It works!!!!! Thanksss!!